# Override localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im building a html,node,js type of web dashboard which shows users information based of sources set from a settings page. The dashboard works as i want it to but currently sources are stored on localStorage but i want to overide localStorage amd use nodelocalstorage instead so that my sources are stored globally on the server side and not just on the clients browser. As i have hopefully understood correctly nodelocalstorage is a server side storage. So how would i be able to overide the browser localstorage.

Answer (score 2):

```
 _________                           ___________
|         |   Internet-connection   |           |
|Webclient| ======================= |  NodeJS-  |
|_________|                         | Webserver |
 ___| |___                          |___________|
```

In most cases **Webclients** are browsers displaying a website served from a webserver. These websites can include javascript to dynamically alter the websites content or work with user inputs. In order for temporary data (e.g. inputs of the user) to be accessible in the future, the webclient has access to `Window.localStorage` (a very primitive data store).

**Webservers** on the other side serve websites and handle api calls to serve data and store this data into databases run on the webserver. *There is also the option to store data within variables in the code running the webserver, which node-localStorage seems to be using. But it is generally not a good idea to store data this way, because, when the server application crashes, the data is gone.* But either way, `node-localStorage` runs on the server and not on the webclient.

And because client and server are completely **different machines** with **different coding environments** it is not possible to implement nodeJS technology on the client side.

But as I understand, what you actually want to achieve is, that the data is stored on the server as you store it in the localStorage of the client. You could actually do that, if you write code on the client, which stores the data in the localStorage and **sends it to the webserver simultaneously**, so that the webserver can store it. But you would also have to push changes from the webserver to the client, if the data can be changed by a third machine. And this would be really tough to implement.